# Python: Extract values from a text file to create nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dictionary, text

I have a text file that is very unorganized with multiple-sub-index objects, something like this:

```
1:
Name of Object 1

Sub-index 0: 
Scale: Q0
Unit: Percent
Description: Object 1 does this

2:
Object 2 yo

Sub-index 0: 
Scale: Q0
Unit: Percent
Description: Something important

Sub-index 1: 
Scale: 0.125
Unit: Percent
Description: Object 2 does that
```

I want to extract these objects' name, scale and description and make them into a dictionary. Something like this:

```
ObjectDict = {
    1: ['Name of Object 1', 'Q0', 'Object 1 does this'],
    2: {
        0: ['Object 2 yo', 'Q0', 'Something important'],
        1: ['Object 2 yo', '0.125', 'Object 2 does that']
    }
}
```

I was able to extract the dictionary keys by doing this:

```
for line in textfile:
    a = line.replace(':', '')
    if b.isnumeric():
        # this is 1 key
```

I can "probably" extract Scale and Description value of an object by doing:

```
if 'Scale' in line: # Store the value
if 'Description' in line: # Store the value
```

However, this would only work if the object only has 1 sub-index. For multiple-sub-index objects like Object 2, I could not figure out how to do them yet. Is there a nice way to do this in Python 3.7? Thanks!

**EDIT: The dictionary format I chose above is just an example. Any other formatted dictionary is okay. I just want to extract necessary data from an unorganized file and store it more properly so other files can access them.**

Comment: Two comments on your choice of data structure: first, I would not recommend have the structure of each element depend on its contents. In your example, having the value for `1` be a list but the value for `2` be a dict doesn't sound like a good idea. Just save a dict with one item. Second, indexing dicts with integers is rarely justified. If that's your usecase, just use lists.

Comment: Your proposed dictionary is far from ideal. You're duplicating information unnecessarily (the object name) and you're losing information (the scale/unit/description property names).

Comment: Regarding you question in particular, I'd branch `if 'Sub-index'  in line` and then just do what you said. But think again about your chosen structure.

Comment: My bad on this. The dictionary I show here is just for example. Any other formatted dictionary should work.

Comment: Please read my added "Edit" comment in the post for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use dictionaries for every object in txt file you can loop through lines of txt file and use some of python builtin functions like `readlines()` and `startswith()` to do what you want.

```
f = open('sample.txt')
lines = f.readlines()
d = {}
for i,line in enumerate(lines):
    if line[:-2].isnumeric():
        ind =  line[:-2]
        name = lines[i+1].replace('\n', '')
        if not ind in d:
            d[ind] = {}

    if line.startswith('Sub-index'):
        sub_ind = line.split()[-1].split(':')[0]
        if not sub_ind in d[ind]:
            d[ind][sub_ind] = []
            d[ind][sub_ind].append(name)

    if line.startswith('Scale'):
        scale = line.split()[-1]
        d[ind][sub_ind].append(scale)

    if line.startswith('Description'):
        desc = line.split(': ')[-1].replace('\n', '')
        d[ind][sub_ind].append(desc)
```

Output:

```
{
    '1': {
        '0': ['Name of Object 1', 'Q0', 'Object 1 does this']
        },
    '2': {
        '0': ['Object 2 yo', 'Q0', 'Something important'],
        '1': ['Object 2 yo', '0.125', 'Object 2 does that']
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That has done the trick. After running it however, I figured that the file has a few objects that does not have "Sub-index" and a "Scale", (so only Name and a Description), so that object's dictionary is empty. I want to add in Sub-index 0 and Scale of 1 for them. Is there a nice way to do that?

Comment: Maybe it is better to have a dictionary for every sub-object instead of list. Then dictionary keys would be `[sub-index, name, scale, description]`. So at the end of loop, if any of keys has no value you can add what you want to it.